# setImageBitmap() modifies the predifined layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I prepared a layout with 2 images of same size in a vertical `LinearLayout` so both appear with exact same size in AS.

The layout is as follow:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/partner_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/fake_background" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/partner_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageGuide"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_Site"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/my_logo"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/partner_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="0dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/partner_logo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/logo_Site"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/my_logo" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"/>

    <ListView android:id="@+id/right_drawer"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="#F2F2F2"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `RelativeLayout`s are here because I will have some other objects in.

[image]

If I execute it on my device, everything is ok, I get the exact same rendering.

But now, I want to change the bottom logo with one downloaded from my server.

I download the exact same image and then, I set it like that:

```
ImageView partnerLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.partner_logo);

file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "/partner/partnerLogo.png");
uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

bitmap = null;
try {
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (bitmap != null) {
    partnerLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

When I look at `bitmap` in the debugger, the image is 512x512 as expected.

But the result is that one:

[image]

Could you tell me why the layout is modified?

**Edit**

I made some tests to try to set both images programmatically and I discovered that using:

```
try {
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (bitmap != null) {
    partnerLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

set an image smaller than using:

```
partnerLogo.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_logo));
```

But both images are exactly the same PNG images!?!

So I think the problem comes from `setImageBimap()` and not from the layout.

**EDIT 2**
According to many post about similar problems, it seems that Android needs a drawable to be able to scale it as needed.
That would confirm my experiment given in first EDIT.

So I tried that:

```
ImageView partnerLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.partner_logo);

file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "/partner/partnerLogo.png");
uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

BitmapDrawable drawable = null;
try {
    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (bitmap != null) {
    partnerLogo.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

But that doesn't work better !?!

Comment: What is the result if you set **match_parent** on both _ImageView_ width and height?

Comment: How does it look like when you set it back to the previous image. Is it maximized again?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the only solution I found is to scale the image by hand, based on the layout built with fake images.
And the code is based on the one found quiet a long time ago somewhere in SO:

```
final ImageView myLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_logo);

bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), R.drawable.my_logo_512x512);
final ImageView partnerLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.partner_logo);

file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), "/partner/partnerLogo.png");
uri = Uri.fromFile(file);

try {
    bitmap2 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (bitmap != null) {

    ViewTreeObserver vto = myLogo.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            myLogo.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            finalHeight = myLogo.getMeasuredHeight();
            finalWidth = myLogo.getMeasuredWidth();
            pictureWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
            pictureHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
            float ratioImage = (float)pictureWidth / (float)pictureHeight;
            float ratioView = (float)finalWidth / (float)finalHeight;

            if (ratioView > ratioImage)  {  // finalHeight is the limit
                finalWidth = (int)((float)pictureWidth * ((float) finalHeight / (float) pictureHeight));
            } else {    // finalWidth is the limit
                finalHeight = (int)((float)pictureHeight * ((float) finalWidth / (float) pictureWidth));
            }

            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, finalWidth, finalHeight, false);
            myLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            if (bitmap2 != null) {
                bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap2, finalWidth, finalHeight, false);
                partnerLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

I saw that a comic downvoted my question, I hope that next time he will motivate it.

Answer (score 0):

On your layout on the LinearLayout add   `android:weightSum="2"`

On your both RelativeLayout containing a ImageView  change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to  `android:layout_height="0dp"`

But those RelativeLayout are superfluous you can remove it and put on the ImageView's

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This ensures that the vertical space will be divided between the two images

Comment: unfortunately, that's not the good answer. First, there are several posts on SO about `weightSum` telling that we don't have to use this field which is calculated by the system. Secondly my `RelativeLayout` are not superfluous because, as I said, I have several objects in it in the final application. And third, `0dp` doesn't solve the problem, it just set the layout padding to `0`.

Comment: For a LinearLayout to evenly distribute the space you need to use weightSum and 0dp + layout_height in the contained views, otherwise LinearLayout simple stacks the views but does not change its size and if a view grows because you assigned a larger image then it will remain large.

Comment: No really, that doesn't work unless there is something I didn't understand so here is my [gist](https://gist.github.com/2ndGAB/3ca3fe32f5e9e417cbc168861b2dbd98)

Comment: try  android:layout_height="match_parent" for both ImageView

Answer (score 0):

Just modified relevant code. Add it and check.
Modification Like:

- Adding weightSum to LinearLayout
- Giving equal weight to the LinearLayout's immediate children

Modified your LinearLayout (partner_layout ). 
This is just modified piece of your XML file.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/partner_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageGuide"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo_Site"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/my_logo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/partner_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:padding="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/partner_logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo_Site"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/my_logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout
```

Comment: That's the same solution as the one given by @Tonteria24 and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Our first aim should be how to resolve the issue.It seems that it could be handled by your xml layout.

So in my suggestion if you are using relative layout try to fix width and height of your imageView.

Other wise try some other layout like tableLayout, frameLayout or gridLyout and try to change width and height of your imageview with various available option(match_parents/wrap_content etc or also try with fix size).and also add

android:scaleType="fitXY"

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: no it doesn't help and `fitXY` won't respect the aspect ratio.

Comment: then set set your imageView's width, height and scale dynamically using java code, where U set your bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

When You set Images from `Drawable` then Android system Automatically resize that image accrding available width and height but when you set Any image using `setImageBitmap()` method it dose not resize and actual image shown.

> Although the system performs scaling and resizing to make your
>   application work on different screens, you should make the effort to
>   optimize your application for different screen sizes and densities. In
>   doing so, you maximize the user experience for all devices and your
>   users believe that your application was actually designed for their
>   devices—rather than simply stretched to fit the screen on their
>   devices.

Find your solution  and more details regarding `Images`,`Bitmap` `scaling` and `resizing` ,`drawables` in below links :

[How to stop Android form automatically scaling drawables?](http://www.thecodecity.com/2015/08/stop-android-form-automatically-scaling-drawables.html)

[Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)